# Sublime Text - Add a header

Tags: text, sublimetext

I found this: https://github.com/kigiri/sublime-header-42

I put on packages folder but when I'm doing ctrl+shift+h, The header doesn't appear.

How can I resolve this?

(My OS: W8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not compatible with Windows out of the box, when I try to install it I have this error in Sublime's console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 550, in run_
    return self.run(edit, **args)
  File "C:\Users\Thibaut\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\sublime-header-42-master\Header.py", line 142, in run
    self.view.replace(edit, line, self.generate(project))
  File "C:\Users\Thibaut\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\sublime-header-42-master\Header.py", line 109, in generate
    created = "Created: " + self.get_date() + " " + self.get_user()
  File "C:\Users\Thibaut\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\sublime-header-42-master\Header.py", line 82, in get_user
    return os.environ['USER']
  File "./os.py", line 676, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'USER'
```

There is no `USER` environment variable on Windows 8+, so you'll probably need to update the script a bit if you want to use it. Simply replacing `os.environ['USER']` with `os.environ['USERNAME']` works fine though.